# Ionic 3 & Angular 4 - How to disable an option if user has already selected it (Page renders before data?)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

A user can select multiple languages they are learning, but they cannot select the same one twice. Therefore the ones they have already selected should be disabled.

> (i use the isDisabled(language) function on the ion-radio component to
>   try and achieve this)

**When i load the page i get the error "Cannot read property 'languages' of undefined". Because i believe it has not finished fetching the user before the html has rendered?**

How can i solve this?

languagelist.html

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" (ngModelChange)="setReadyState()">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let language of languages">
            <ion-label color="dark">{{language.name}}</ion-label>
            <ion-note item-end>{{language.native}}</ion-note>
            <ion-radio [value]="language" [disabled]="isDisabled(language)"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

languagelist.ts

```
export class LanguageListPage {

    languages: any;
    isReadyToSave: boolean;
    user:any;
    selectedLanguage :any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public navParams: NavParams,
                public util: UtilProvider,
                public viewCtrl: ViewController,
                public auth: Auth,
                public userProvider: User) {

        this.getLanguages();
        this.getUser();


    }

    getLanguages() {
        this.util.getLanguages().subscribe((resp) => {
            this.languages = resp.json();
            console.log(resp.json());
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    done() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.selectedLanguage);
    }

    isDisabled(language) {

        for(let i = 0; i < this.user.languages.teach; i++)
        {
            if(this.user.languages.teach[i].code === language.code)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    getUser() {
        let id = this.auth.getUser()._id;

        this.userProvider.get(id).subscribe(resp => {
            this.user = resp.json();
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple write

```
        <ion-radio [value]="language" 
          [disabled]="language === selectedLanguage"></ion-radio>
```

I have read your title just set up your initial value on languages variable and change disabled state function to .

```
    isDisabled(language) { 
      if (this.user && this.user.languages && this.user.languages.teach) { 
         return this.user.languages.teach.some((lang) => { 
             return lang.code === language.code 
         }) 
    } 
     return false; 
}
```

Comment: i dont have the variable selectedLanguage, i need to get all the selected languages from the user object this is why im doing getUser().

Comment: ngModel :-) selectedLanguage You have it. Just try

Comment: i dont think you understand my question. THAT selectedLanguage is the new one they will select.

Comment: i was reading your title. To fix the problem with languages just initiate them in your component. Cause when your component initialize the languages is undefined thats why you see error

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what youre trying to say... Can you explain an answer in full detail pls.

Comment: Whyn your component initializing the variable languages undefined thats why ngFor is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154619/discussion-between-alexkhymenko-and-kay).